# Rounding with midnight seconds in DB2

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

Maybe this is more simple than I realize, but I'm trying to simply look at records like the ones below and add up the timestamps but for grouping where the difference is only in seconds, my result set is 0 but I'd like to get this in a decimal for second counts as well.

I'm using DB2 on AS400 iSeries Version 7

Sample data

```
JOB_STATUS   |   JOB_STATUS_TIME
---------------------------------------------
 P                2019-10-02  08:47:12.362261
 P                2019-10-02  08:47:22.362261 
 P                2019-10-02  08:47:32.362261
 P                2019-10-02  08:47:42.362261
 P                2019-10-02  08:47:52.362261
```

Query:

```
SELECT
SUM
(
 CASE A1.JOB_STATUS WHEN 'P' THEN
(DAYS(A2.JOB_STATUS_TIME) - DAYS(A1.JOB_STATUS_TIME)) * 86400
 + MIDNIGHT_SECONDS(A2.JOB_STATUS_TIME) - 
 MIDNIGHT_SECONDS(A2.JOB_STATUS_TIME)
 END
 ) / 60 AS ACTIVE_MINUTES 
FROM SCHEMA.TABLE;
```

I tried adding `ROUND({sum query}, 2)` but that didn't work for me, still returned zero

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all the columns and values used in a division operation are `INGEGER` (or `BIGINT` or `SMALLINT`) then the division will be an integer division.

You need to cast something to DECIMAL or use a decimal, float of DECFLOAT value to get decimal division. E.g.  try dividing by `60.0`

```
SELECT
   SUM(CASE A1.JOB_STATUS WHEN 'P' THEN
        (DAYS(A2.JOB_STATUS_TIME) - DAYS(A1.JOB_STATUS_TIME)) * 86400
       + MIDNIGHT_SECONDS(A2.JOB_STATUS_TIME)
       - MIDNIGHT_SECONDS(A1.JOB_STATUS_TIME)
 END
 ) / 60.0 AS ACTIVE_MINUTES 
FROM
   SCHEMA.TABLE
```

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafz2intoper.htm

> If both operands of an arithmetic operator are integers with zero scale, the operation is performed in binary, and the result is a large integer unless either (or both) operand is a big integer, in which case the result is a big integer. *Any remainder of division is lost*

Comment: Ok so that did return a decimal, but it's 0.000000000 which still seems odd since there are definitely differences in seconds. Is it the usage of midnight_seconds that might be throwing it off?

Comment: You have `A2.JOB_STATUS_TIME` in both the `+` and `-` clauses.  Once needs to be `A1`

Comment: Of course! No idea how that happened, but thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit off topic, but I think what you do can be done with

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(2, MAX(JOB_STATUS_TIME) - MIN(JOB_STATUS_TIME) )
```